# Generic Class as a Default Response

Tags: kotlin

I was trying to create a default response class for my API, thus avoiding returning the specific object.

But the problem is, in **Java** I can do it, but in **Kotlin** I can't :( .

Here is my Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/search/{title}")
    fun returnMovie(@PathVariable("title") title: String,
                    @RequestHeader("include_adult") includeAdult: Boolean,
                    @RequestHeader("page") page: String,
                    @RequestHeader("language") language: String): Response {
        //WHAT I HAVE TO DO?
        return movieClient.getMovie(title, includeAdult, page, language, apiKey)
    }
```

Previously it was directly returning the Movie object.

```
    @Document
    data class Movie(
        @Id
        val id: String? = ObjectId.get().toString(),
        val genre_ids: List<Int>?,
        val original_language: String?,
        val original_title: String?,
        val overview: String?,
        val release_date: Date?
    )
```

But now, I would like to return this object with a generic field so I can assign other objects.

```
    data class Response(
        val page: Int?,
        val content: MutableList<T>?,
        val total_pages: Int?,
        val total_results: Int?
    )
```

UPDATE

Here is the return

```
{
"page": 1,
"results": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
],
"total_pages": 1,
"total_results": 18
```

}

How can I bind my Movie object to the content parameter generic ?

**UPDATE**

I get a response from this API via FeignClient and it was mapping to the Movie object.

```
@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET], value = ["search/movie"], consumes = ["application/json"])
fun getMovie(@RequestParam("query") query: String,
             @RequestParam("include_adult") includeAdult: Boolean,
             @RequestParam("page") page: String,
             @RequestParam("language") language: String,
             @RequestParam("api_key") apiKey: String): MutableList<Movie>
```

Comment: I think Response is a reserved keyword. Try using some other words. Btw what exactly is the error?

Comment: Hey Rajen, thks for the reply. I updated the question. And I tried to change the name to DefaultResponse but still not working.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43935291/3831557) may be it will give some info. I see issue may be due to use of T a generic type.

Comment: I updated the question with more information about how a receive data.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your issue:

`val content: MutableList<T>?`

The `T` doesn't make sense there, that is a typed parameter that is for generic functions and etc. If you want a list of any (hint) type of object, you need your list to be

`val content: MutableList<Any>?`